# Read data from BigQuery and write it into avro file format on cloud storage

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, avro

My objective is to read the data from BigQuery table and write it to Avro file on cloud storage using Java. It would be good if some one provide the code snipet/ideas to write BigQuery table data and write it to avro format data using Cloud Dataflow.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to export data from BigQuery to GCS as Avro format as a one-time export, this can be done through the Client Libraries, including Java. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#exporting_data_stored_in) are some snippets (the full example can be found in GitHub), and for java you can code:

```
Job job = table.extract(format, gcsUrl);
// Wait for the job to complete
try {
  Job completedJob =
      job.waitFor(
          RetryOption.initialRetryDelay(Duration.ofSeconds(1)),
          RetryOption.totalTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(3)));
  if (completedJob != null && completedJob.getStatus().getError() == null) {
    // Job completed successfully
  } else {
    // Handle error case
  }
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
  // Handle interrupted wait
}
```

The [format variable](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#export_formats_and_compression_types) can be CSV, JSON or AVRO and the gcsUtl variable should contain bucket and path to the file, e.g. gs://my_bucket/filename

Comment: I am looking to establish ETL process with GCP dataflow,So I cant go for manual process from BQ console UI.

Comment: I think the link Flavien provided also has instruction for how to do it programmatically (such as from Java) as well, so you don't have to do it from the BQ Console UI. Also, I think Cloud Dataflow support reading directly from a BigQuery table instead of a GCS location, so maybe you wouldn't need to write to GCS after all?